# Using the paste command with awk

Tags: variables, awk, paste, tcsh

The purpose of my script is to take the second column of each text file in a directory and paste the results in a text file column by column.

For example, if I have three text files with the format:

```
 age 30

 gender m

 weight 200
```

I want the output to be

```
 age 30 40 50

 gender m m f.

 weight 200 194 143
```

This is my current code:

```
 !/bin/csh
 set z = "e"

 foreach y (*.txt)


 if ($z == "e") then

 echo "creating first columns for $y"

 awk '{print $1}' $y  > $SUBJECTS_DIR/vol_files/$y:r_rhvol.txt

 else

 echo "first columns have already been created for $y"

 endif


 echo "now adding the data for $y"

 set v = (awk '{print $2}' $y) 

 paste $v >> $SUBJECTS_DIR/vol_files/$y:r_rhvol.txt

 set z = "f"
 end
```

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to google [CSH why not](https://www.google.com/search?q=csh+why+not&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 2):

Here one to keep you entertained while I whip something up:

```
$ join foo <(join foo foo )
age 30 30 30

gender m m m

weight 200 200 200
```

Here's one in awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] (a[$1]==""?"":OFS) $2}END{for(i in a)print i, a[i]}' foo foo foo

age 30 30 30
weight 200 200 200
gender m m m
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
{ a[$1]=a[$1] (a[$1]==""?"":OFS) $2 }  # hash on the first field and append append
END { for(i in a)                      # after all files hashed
          print i, a[i] }              # print (in random order, though)
' foo foo foo
```

Comment: Doesn't matter in this case since `$1` can't be null given the OPs data and FS but FYI in general `a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS : "") $2` is more robust (and IMHO a bit clearer) than `a[$1]=a[$1] (a[$1]==""?"":OFS) $2` for testing whether or not this is the first time populating `a[$1]` so it's good to get into the habit of doing that since there's no downside to it and you don't have to think about what the input values might be before deciding if you should use it or not - anything that reduces thinking is good :-).

Comment: @EdMorton I need to try not to think about that for a while... :D But you're right and it looks less messy. I need to hack it into my dna somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Short solution with ***paste*** + ***awk*** pipeline for multiple files with known structure.

Let's say we have 5 files(could be much more):

```
paste $SUBJECTS_DIR/vol_files/*.txt | awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2) $i=""}1'
```

The exemplary output:

```
age 30  40  50  60  70
gender m  m  f.  e  g
weight 200  194  143  300  400
```

---

`awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2) $i=""}1'` - removes repeated caption columns `age , gender ...` from joined lines